# No deadlock while incrementing synchronized Integer objects

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, java.util.concurrent

I am tried to implement deadlock in my program and all was ok except one issue which I can't explain.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Integer balanceA = 10000;
        Integer balanceB = 10000;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                Processor.run(balanceA, balanceB);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                Processor.run(balanceB, balanceA);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}

class Processor {
    public static void run(Integer balanceA, Integer balanceB) {
        synchronized (balanceA) {
            synchronized (balanceB) {
                System.out.println(balanceA++ + "; " + balanceB--);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why it always show me the same result as if I did't modify Integer values:

10000; 10000

10000; 10000

...

Comment: because you don't. you first print the (local) variable, and after that, you alter the value. but it's only the local value you alter, so not the value that is being passed the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`balanceA++` is equivalent to `balanceA = balance + 1`. It doesn't modify the `Integer` (it can't, because `Integer` is immutable). It just changes the value of the `balanceA` parameter to refer to a different object.

If you use `AtomicInteger` and call either `incrementAndGet` or `getAndIncrement`, *then* you'll see the values changing. You also won't need any synchronization.